# How to insert in to MDB using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, jet

```
Dim MyInsert As String = "INSERT INTO Inventory(userid,
Type,Number) Values(" & _
txtEquipCat.text & "," & _
Type.Text & "," & _
Number.text & ")"
```

while executing this im getting

> syntax error:Insert in to statement

error.

How to insert keywords like type and number in to MDB?
I want to specify the columnname while insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use parameters.  Secondly, your string concoction isn't putting "quotes" around the text.

That is, `VALUES ('" & txtEquipCat.Text & "',...`

Don't try to fix it like that though.

Use parameters: `VALUES (?, ?, ?)`

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtEquipCat.Text)
```

Notice with parameters, you do not have to worry about any quotation marks.  The parameters have to be entered in order, so the first "?" corresponds to txtEquipCat, the second to Type.Text, etc.

Comment: @user833985 If your field names in the data table are "Type" and "Number", I "think" you just have to put brackets around them, like "[Type]" and "[Number]".  I'm not 100% that works, but I'm guessing if you are getting an error on those fields, you would need the brackets.